# Line integral of a vector function involving sine and cosine

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I have line integral of a vector function: $\vec{F}=-e^{-x}\sin y\,\,\vec{i}+e^{-x}\cos y\,\,\vec{j}$
The path is a square on the $xy$ plane with vertices at $(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)$

Of course it is a closed line integral, and I know the result should be zero.

I am baffled how can you calculate $\sin y$ or $\cos y$ where $y$ is an actual coordinate point?!

Comment: If you mean how do you simplify for example $\sin1$, well basically you can't, it is just $\sin1$.  Of course you could find it approximately as a decimal by using a calculator.  But maybe I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant, how can you simplify sin 1, may be convert it to polar, I don't know!

Comment: It is not always true that a closed line integral will give zero. This is only true for very specific kinds of functions $\vec{F}$: ones that satisfy $\vec{F} = \nabla\phi$ for some continuously differentiable $\phi$.

Comment: As I said, you really can't simplify $\sin1$.  Have you actually tried working out the integral yet?  If you get $\sin1$ at all in your answer, you may find that it comes as something like $(\sin1)-(\sin1)$ which of course is very easy to simplify ;-)

Comment: The line integral need be $0$ if $\vec{F}$ is a gradient. However $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(e^{-x}\sin(y))=e^{-x}\cos(y)\ne-e^{-x}\cos(y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(e^{-x}\cos(y))$$ so $\vec{F}$ is a not gradient.

Comment: @CameronWilliams it is F = grad(theta). So it has to be zero. plus that is what the text book says! However my question is how can you simplify such equation whether the result is zero or not! May be David is right..you just can't simplify it!

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks for the edit Cameron. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, have you computed $\nabla \times \vec{F}$ and verified that is $\vec{0}$? Let's see: $$\nabla \times \vec{F} = \left|\begin{array}\vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k} \\ \partial_x & \partial_y & \partial_z \\ e^{-x} \sin y & e^{-x} \cos y & 0 \end{array}\right| = (0,0,-e^{-x} \cos y - e^{-x} \cos y) \neq \vec{0}$$
This way, the integral does not have to be zero. In fact, using Green's Theorem, we get $$\begin{align} \int_C \vec{F} ~\mathrm{d}r &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 -2e^{-x} \cos y ~\mathrm{d}x~ \mathrm{d}y \\ &= -2 \int_0^1e^{-x} \mathrm{d}x \int_0^1 \cos y~\mathrm{d}y \\ &= -2 (-e^{-1} - (-e^{-0}))(\sin 1 - \sin 0)  \\ &= -2\left(1-\frac{1}{e}\right) \sin 1 \\ &= 2\left(\frac{1}{e}-1\right) \sin 1\end{align}$$
And $\sin 1$ is a number, so we just leave at that.

Comment: I'm opposed to this solution. It's not *incorrect* since you can extend the function to $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the obvious way but it is misleading since the more fundamental property to ensure a line integral of $0$ ($\vec{F} = \nabla\phi$) holds for $\mathbb{R}^n$ in general. This kind of approach would fail for $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @Ivo Terek I am so sorry, it is actually (-e^(-x) sin(y))i. so the curl would be zero. I don't know how to write equation in the "fancy way" and another user has thankfully edited my question for me. the negative sign was dropped either by me or him!. Nevertheless you have answered my question, sin(1) has to be just a number!! Thanks to you and David.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've changed the function, we have
$$
(-e^{-x}\sin(y),e^{-x}\cos(y))=\nabla e^{-x}\sin(y)
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\oint\nabla (e^{-x}\sin(y))\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{r}
&=e^{-x}\sin(y)\Big]_{(0,0)}^{(0,0)}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I edited your post slightly for clarity. I hope you don't mind!